# Two events on one onclick

Tags: javascript, dom-events, buttonclick

I am facing this issue:

```
<p class="pushButton">
  <a href="javascript:return;"
      onclick="SetOkCodeButton('=SC_ORDER', 'BBPForm', '', '',''); 
      return false;" name="Order" class="pushButton" 
      title="Orders your shopping cart. This completes the operation "
      onmouseover="status=' ';return true;"  onmouseout="status=' ';">
      &nbsp;Order&nbsp;
  </a>
</p>

<p class="pushButton">
  <a href="javascript:return;" 
      onclick="SetOkCodeButton('=SC_REFRESH', 'BBPForm', '', '',''); 
      return false;" name="Refresh" class="pushButton" 
      title="Updates all details according to your changes. "
      onmouseover="status=' ';return true;"  onmouseout="status=' ';">
      &nbsp;Refresh&nbsp;
   </a>
</p>
```

I need to change the functionality of the <kbd>ORDER</kbd> button. It should trigger the `REFRESH` (generating the `SC_REFRESH` event) functionality right before the `SC_ORDER` event is generated.

It means I need to trigger two events with one `onlick` on the <kbd>ORDER</kbd> button - first `REFRESH` and then `ORDER`. With 2 second time break between the two events.
The functionality of `REFRESH` will not change.

Answer (score 2):

A). What's the reason for the 2-sec delay? This is extremely suspicious...

B). Any given method should achieve exactly one thing well. Creating different functionality for REFRESH and ORDER within the method suggests to me that you really have two methods which should be broken into two (which perhaps both call a common third function), but then again I'm struggling to imagine why you would want to refresh the form *before* posting it.

C). If you really need this you can introduce a timer with [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_settimeout.asp) preferably into the newly divided method itself, but if you continue with the existing implementation then I guess in the onclick attribute itself, though now it gets messy(er). You'd write something like this:

```
onclick="SetOkCodeButton('=SC_REFRESH', 'BBPForm', '', '',''); setTimeout(function(){SetOkCodeButton('=SC_ORDER', 'BBPForm', '', '','');},2000);"
```

Note though that setTimeout is asynchronous - if you want a real wait() method you'll need to write one yourself (and these are processor expensive), but they're expensive and again I doubt you really need it.

D). The return false is also deeply suspicious...

E). Likewise with the mouseouts and overs, is this auto-generated code?

Comment: The return false; statement cancels the default action of the link (navigating to the anchor location). Because of this the href="javascript:return;" attributes could simply be replaced with href="#".

Comment: If you're putting that much code into the onclick attribute you'd be much better breaking it out to a function into a script block for readability and ease of maintenance.

Comment: onclick doesn't require return false, hrefs do (and javascript: void foo() is a safer, clearer way to do that - and I couldn't agree more that this is horrible code - see points A,B,D and E :)

Comment: If you have a href="#" attribute on the link as I described the return false statement at the end of the onclick handler is necessary if you want to prevent the browser from scrolling to the top of your page.

Comment: Using the JavaScript pseudo protocol can result in obscure problems in Internet Explorer: http://blog.reindel.com/2006/08/11/a-hrefjavascriptvoid0-avoid-the-void/

http://jibbering.com/faq/#javascriptURI details further why it's best to avoid using the JavaScript pseudo-protocol in anchor hrefs.

Comment: Well yeah there's a lot of strikes against this in general (which is why I'd avoid it entirely and work with JS event binding) but given the lack of choice I find the risk/burden of return false > than the risk of an obscure IE bug with a bad img swap technique anyway. Basically it all sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason this won't work?

```
<p class="pushButton">
  <a href="javascript:return;" 
      onclick="SetOkCodeButton('=SC_REFRESH', 'BBPForm', '', '','');SetOkCodeButton('=SC_ORDER', 'BBPForm', '', '','');
      return false;" name="Refresh" class="pushButton" 
      title="Updates all details according to your changes. "
      onmouseover="status=' ';return true;"  onmouseout="status=' ';">
       Refresh 
   </a>
</p>
```

If those functions are synchronous, this should be OK, if they're async, you'll likely need a callback.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the code I listed here is generated by this template from SAP.
I am new in this. :-)
Anybody can see a chance to trigger 2 events (SC_REFRESH and SC_ORDER) instead of just one (SC_ORDER)?

`TR()` `TD()`

`BBPVSpace()`
`BBPButtonBegin()`

`if (BTN_SC_ORDER.exists)` 
      `if (BTN_SC_ORDER.disabled)` 
          `BBPDisabledButton(BTN_SC_ORDER.label)`
          `BBPButtonSpace()`
      `else`
          `BBPButton(BTN_SC_ORDER.OKCODE,BTN_SC_ORDER.label, tooltip=#BUTTON_ORDER)`
          `BBPButtonSpace()`
      `end`
  `end`

`if (BTN_SC_REFRESH.exists)` 
      `if (BTN_SC_REFRESH.disabled)` 
          `BBPDisabledButton(BTN_SC_REFRESH.label)`
          `BBPButtonSpace()`
        `else`
          `BBPButton(BTN_SC_REFRESH.OKCODE,BTN_SC_REFRESH.label,tooltip=#BUTTON_ACTUAL)`
          `BBPButtonSpace()`
      `end`
    `end`